# Sitecore how to show item's field in a datasource instead of item name

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In a templateItem I have following information for a field.

```
Name : Product type
field type : 'Droplink' 
DataSource : DataSource=/sitecore/content/Enumerations/Products/Product type/
```

When the content editor creates an item based on above template, for the field '`Product type`' in the dropdown he will see the items under `../Product type`. My question is for the items which are show in dropdown how to show some other field instead of item name

Comment: Not out of the box, you'll have to create a custom field.

Comment: Yes the field 'Title' I already have But I don't know how I can access it.

Comment: No, I mean you will have to create a custom field: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/best-practice-blogs/martin-knudsen/posts/2012/09/creating-a-custom-sitecore-field.aspx

Comment: thanks for comment. I have updated my question. I guess previously I was not clear enough.

Comment: The question was clear, but it requires a custom field. I added an answer to achieve what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This functionality does not exist out of the box, although the code for the DropLink field looks like has code in there to be able to do this (take a look at the `GetItemHeader()` method in `Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor.LookupEx`), I do not know how to utilize the parameter through the Content Editor though...

It's simple enough to create a custom field to achieve this though:

```
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentEditor;

namespace MyProject.Custom.Fields
{
    public class CustomDropLink : LookupEx
    {
        protected override string GetItemHeader(Item item)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FieldName))
                this.FieldName = StringUtil.ExtractParameter("FieldName", this.Source).Trim();

            return base.GetItemHeader(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Then register your custom class in the `core` database under `/sitecore/system/Field types/`. You can do this by duplicating `/sitecore/system/Field types/Link Types/Droplink` and setting the following values:

```
Assembly: MyProject.Custom
Class: MyProject.Custom.Fields.CustomDropLink
Control: <set this to empty>
```

Then when you utilise this field set the Source of your field like so:

`Datasource=/sitecore/content/path/to/items&FieldName=Title`